# Referencing the RecordType Name instead of the ID in a test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage, record-type

I have a test class which all works perfectly in the Sandbox however when i push to live it fails.

On looking into it i have seen that my RecordTypeID is different in sandbox as it is in production.. Therefore i wondered if i could reference the Record Type name which is the same in both?

I have tried RecordTypeName and RecordType.Name but both throw up errors,

Any ideas>?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the record type's name is unique, you can get away with not using a describe method at all:

```
TASKRAY_Project__c project = new TASKRAY_Project__c(
    RecordType = new RecordType(Name='Phase'),
    ...);
```

You can also create the RecordType ahead of time and use it as a variable:

```
RecordType phaseRT = new RecordType(Name='Phase');
...
TASKRAY_Project__c project = new TASKRAY_Project__c(
    RecordType = phaseRT,
    ...);
```

This is great for creating many records of the same record type.

Comment: Assuming the instantiated `RecordType` object works the same way as it does in SOQL, you could also specify `sObjectType`, which is a picklist, or add the `DeveloperName` if the `Name` is not unique.  I've never used a `RecordType` as an object before though, so I don't know if this works.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Actually, it only works with indexed fields, unfortunately. I tried DeveloperName before I posted this answer to be sure. As a side note: why isn't DeveloperName an indexed field? *sigh*

Comment: Ahh, good to know then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Custom Setting` to store information about `RecordTypes` you need, and then use them in your `test class`, and you have to use the correct value in each `Org` (`production` and `sandbox`).

When assigning a `recordType` in your `test class`, you have to use `Id`  instead of `Name`.

**Edit**

This is how you can use `Custom Setting` in your `test class` :

Imagine the name you give to your `custom setting` is `IdRecordType` : the `API name` will be `IdRecordType__c` and then in `manage button` you define instance called '`General`' (where you can give values to your variables), so in your code you should put :

```
 IdRecordType__c confTR = IdRecordType__c.getInstance('General');

 myCustomSetting.yourvariablesname__c...
```

Comment: Hi @ihssan do i write that into the test class or hold it in the controller?

And how exactly would i write that as ive never used that before?

Comment: This is a video tutorial for creating a `custom setting` [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMddRjgs-2Y),  i will edit my answer to show you how to use it in your test class

Comment: Thanks all just trying @sfdcfox method now as it seemed quite simple. The test class has passed and i am uploading into production now to test

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can retrieve the Record Type Id by using the Schema methods as follows, obviously change the object name for 'Case' and the Developer name for the record type - always use developer names for these as they are more likely to be static.

```
RecordTypeCaseId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Metering').getRecordTypeId();
```

Answer (score 0):

One method that has the advantage of being dynamic while allowing you to specify an object is to use `SOQL`.  You can query the [`RecordType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) object like any other object.  In your case, you could use:

```
RecordTypeID = [select ID from RecordType where Name = 'XXX' and
                            sObjectType = 'TASKRAY__Project__c'].ID
//Or possibly "sObjectType = 'Project__c' and NamespacePrefix = 'TASKRAY'", 
//I have not tried with an object with a namespace
```